# Including function in script throws object undefined error in Javascript

Tags: jquery, properties, hide

I would like to know how to hide a form element based on 2 criteria ,the type and the value.  I have a button that has a value of "Save".  So the input is type:button, value:Save.  Is it possible to hide the button based on these 2 criteria.  The reason I'm asking is there are other elements on the page that have the same value but different types.
I was using this which (of course) does not work:

```
 $("input[val='Save',type='button']").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add an id to that particular input?

```
<input id="button-id" type="button" value="Save" />
```

That way you wouldn't need to worry about accessing that particular input tag over type and value as it would be unique in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

a filter could work

```
$("input[type=button]").filter(function() {
 var buttonvalue = this.value;
;
 return buttonvalue === 'save';
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a [multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

try

```
$("input[val='Save'][type='button']").hide();
```